# Не работает destroy при касание с объектом в юнити

Tags: unity3d

Не работает destroy в юнити, в чем может быть ошибка

```
public class Kipr : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject player ;
        void start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FinWithTag("tag1");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Destroy(player.transform);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Почему `Destroy` в `Update`? Вы понимаете смысл этих методов?
И попробуйте просто  `Destroy(player);`. Но переместите в другой метод.

Comment: что бы отследить касания вам нужны коллайдеры. 

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: не FinWithTag, а Fin**d**WithTag

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DestroyPlayerOnCollision: MonoBehaviour
{
    //Если была коллизия c любым обьектом - унчитожить обьект с этим скриптом
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        transform.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй этот код. На объект "Player" поставь компонент Rigidbody, любой компонент Collision и этот скрипт.

```
public class Kipr : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject player;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("tag1");
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Destroy(player);
    } 
}
```